# Creating Simple Console App using .NET Core 2.0

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I downloaded this [sample MSGraph console app](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/console-csharp-connect-sample) and got it to run.  It uses .NET 4.6.1. I'm trying to convert it to .NET Core 2.0.  I'm unable to install MSGraph using this NuGet package:
Install-Package Microsoft.Graph -Version 1.11.0

It gives the following error:

```
Installing Microsoft.Graph 1.11.0.
Install-Package : NU1605: Detected package downgrade: Microsoft.Graph.Core from 1.11.0 to 1.10.0. Reference the     package directly from the project to select a different version.
 ConsoleMSGraph -> Microsoft.Graph 1.11.0 -> Microsoft.Graph.Core (>= 1.11.0)
 ConsoleMSGraph -> Microsoft.Graph.Core (>= 1.10.0)
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Microsoft.Graph -Version 1.11.0
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId :     NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

Install-Package : Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for 'ConsoleMSGraph'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Microsoft.Graph -Version 1.11.0
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId :     NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

Time Elapsed: 00:00:14.1377482
PM>
```

Is there an MSGraph package that works with .NET Core 2.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing some repro steps. That sample target 1.7.0 of the client. Yes, that package will work with Net Core 2. It targets NetStandard 1.1. Here's a Net Core 2 sample:
https://github.com/MIchaelMainer/GraphNetCore2

Comment: We are working on more Net Core samples. Keep your eyes open under github.com/microsoftgraph